# sub domain to different computers

Tags: redirects, multiple-domains

I am hosting a personal website domain.tld and have a separate nas computer as nas.domain.tld and I only have 1 public ip address.  I have successfully redirected nas.domain.tld to domain.tld:99 so when you access nas.domain.tld, domain.tld or [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) you are directed to the appropriate computer.

I have set up ssl on the domain.tld for secure connections through letsencrypt certbot and would like to do the same for the nas.domain.tld but it fails:

```
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: nas.domain.tld
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://nas.domain.tld/.well-known/acme-challenge/key
   [ipv6]: 204

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

when you access nas.domain.tld the browser reports domain.tld:99

I could have a redirect on my domain.tld server to redirect to the correct port but I prefer to offload that workflow to the modem.  Is there a way to do this and utilize ssl support?

domain.tld is offered through apache2
nas.domain.tld is offered through nginx (which is listening on port 99)

update: My question is related to how (if) it's possible to create the valid certificate on the nas server since it reports as domain.tld:99 and if it can be done through letsencrypt.

Comment: Is your question about how to set up the subdomain for external access or about how to get a LetsEncrypt certificate?

Comment: You may want to read https://serverfault.com/questions/805666/certbot-letsencrypt-on-different-port-than-443

Comment: Thank you davidgo, researching the links in that thread resolved my question.  Now I just have to figure out the config files of nginx and redirect to the new port therein.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you indicate in the comments that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers.